# VSTS permissions to allow all users to view images added to bugs/tasks

Tags: azure-devops

Good afternoon,

I'm having some issues with VSTS and i am unable to find a single reference to anyone else experiencing this issue.

We use Microsoft's [Test and Feedback](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-exploratorytesting-web&utm_source=vsts%20XT&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=vsts%20XT%20tip) browser extension for our support team and developers to add useful screen shots or walk through videos of bugs and tasks into VSTS.

This is affecting everyone except me (i'm administrator) which leads me to think this may be a permission issue that i am not finding the settings for. But certain images added to tasks or bugs are broken for my developers - as if they do not have permissions to view them. And as i said they display fine for me.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I believe this is directly related to **Test and Feedback** images that have the following URL: *xxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection//TestManagement/v1.0/…?.....* When user clicks the broken image they get:

> "You do not have the appropriate permissions to read to the project."

This makes no sense because they are able to read other tasks and image in the same project, including other tasks with images generated by Test and Feedback. It does not appear to be happening with directly uploaded images.

Additionally i have some users who are unable to use the @ tagging in comments in VSTS, whihc i suspect is also a permisisons issue.

What permissions do i need to give (if any) to allow users to view images added to bugs and tasks via Test and Feedback or allow users to tag other people in comments?

Thanks

Comment: I am not 100% sure this will help which is why I am not providing this as an answer but maybe set your dev team permissions so that they include the 'reviewer' permissions described in this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/feedback/give-permissions-feedback?view=vsts

Comment: @JasonH thanks for the feedback - it's nice to know i'm getting some eyes on this. Currently the team has all the permissions mentioned in your link set to allow. This includes "Create test runs", "View Project-Level Info", "View Test runs" and at the Area level "Edit work items in this node" and "View work items in this node"...

Answer (score 0):

There has no additional permissions to view images in work items (such as bugs or tasks).

If the images are not display when you open a work item, please check the browser you are using. Options you can have a try as below:

- Use another web browser to check if the images can be displayed.
- Clear browser cache and cookies etc, then open a work item again.

Comment: Marina, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that's just not the case here. We running every major browser here (we're a tech company) with all same results. It's also happening to multiple users on our dev team except me who is admin on the account and project...

Comment: What if you manually add a image in a work item, does the image display?

Comment: I believe this is directly related to Test and Feedback images that have the following URL: https://xxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection//TestManagement/v1.0/AttachmentDownload.ashx?..... When user clicks the broken image they get a "You do not have the appropriate permissions to read to the project." - Which makes no sense cause he is able to read other tasks and image in the same project. Also the same user with the issue might see some images uploaded from Test and Feedback while other given them this permissions error. It does not appear to be happening with directly uploaded images.

Comment: VSTS has no such url `https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TestManagement/v1.0/AttachmentDownload.ashx`. How did you add images with these url?

Comment: Via Test and Feedback browser extension for VSTS. Note this URL works for some, so it's not the URL that's the issue.